# Setting an Azure Scheduler Job Retry Policy

Tags: azure, scheduler

Using the Azure Management REST API, I'm trying to update (PATCH) an existing Scheduler job with a retry policy. The request is accepted but the json response object doesn't include the retry policy entries.

In the case of an update, other changes I make are reflected in the response.

Azure Scheduler job entity structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn528941.aspx

Azure Scheduler REST API ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn528946.aspx

I've be using Burp Suite to quickly iterate through different requests, but I never see anything to suggest the retry policy has been created.

What am I missing?

The following request will create a new job name SampleJob20 (with no retry policy)

```
PUT /<subid>/cloudservices/<cloudservicename>/resources/scheduler/~/JobCollections/<jobcollectionname>/jobs/SampleJob20?api-version=2014-04-01 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
x-ms-version: 2012-03-01
Host: management.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 583



{
    "startTime": "2013-01-30T12:08:00-08:00",
    "action":
    {
        "type": "http",
        "request":
        {
            "uri": "http://bing.com/",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": 
            {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            }
        }
    },
    "recurrence":
    {
        "frequency": "minute",
        "interval": 30,
        "count": 1000
    },
    "state": "enabled"
}
```

The response for this request is:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 364
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: 1.0.6198.148 (rd_rdfe_stable.141019-1428) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
x-ms-request-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 19:13:40 GMT

{
    "id":"SampleJob20",
    "startTime":"2013-01-30T20:08:00Z",
    "action":
    {
        "request":
        {
            "uri":"http:\/\/bing.com\/","method":"GET",
            "headers":
            {
                "content-Type":"text\/plain"
            }
        },
        "type":"http"
    },
    "recurrence":
    {
        "frequency":"minute",
        "count":1000,
        "interval":30
    },
    "state":"enabled",
    "status":
    {
        "nextExecutionTime":"2014-10-20T19:38:00Z",
        "executionCount":0,
        "failureCount":0,
        "faultedCount":0
    }
}
```

When I try and update this job with a retry policy. The response is missing the retry policy detail.

```
PATCH /<subid>/cloudservices/<cloudservicename>/resources/scheduler/~/JobCollections/<jobcollectionname>/jobs/SampleJob20?api-version=2014-04-01 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
x-ms-version: 2012-03-01
Host: management.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 451



{
    "id": "SampleJob20",
    "action":
        {
            "type": "http",
            "request":
            {
                    "uri": "http://bing.com",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": 
                    {
                        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
                    }
            },

            "retryPolicy": 
            {
                "retryType":"fixed",
                "retryInterval": "PT1M",
                "retryCount": 3
            }
        }
}
```

If I create a new job with a retry policy the response contains the retry detail. However, the jobs retry policy cannot be updated either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting a new or the same job like this (It includes the retry policy in the Put request)

PUT

```
{
"startTime": "2013-01-30T12:08:00-08:00",
"action":
{
    "type": "http",
    "request":
    {
        "uri": "http://bing.com/",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": 
        {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    },
       "retryPolicy": 
        {
            "retryType":"fixed",
            "retryInterval": "PT1M",
            "retryCount": 3
        }
},
"recurrence":
{
    "frequency": "minute",
    "interval": 30,
    "count": 1000
},
"state": "enabled"
}
```

Comment: Yes this works OK. The retry policy is set. If I then send another PUT with a change to the retry policy (or any other changes) this is reflected in the response. The issue is with submitting a PATCH request. When I submit a PATCH request to say change the URL this works OK. If I sent a PATCH request to update the retry policy (change it to retryCount to 4) this does not work.

Comment: Andy, we did not support path for the retry policy yet. I've added it now and you should be able to make the same patch request as in your question above and see it succeed.(will be shipped in about 2 weeks from now)